# Consolidate components to avoid import of multiple classes

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need two components for my tabs-module.

```
<tabs>
```

and

```
<tab>
```

To use this tabs I have to import like this:

```
import { Tabs, Tab } from '../../components/tabs/tabs.component';
```

In this case their are only two components. But I am planing components with more "child-components". Is there a way to consolidate them?

Comment: How do you want to consolidate? They are separate classes. If you want to import the whole module, use `import * as TabComponentModule from '../../components/tabs/tabs.component`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript allows you to [import the entire module into a single variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import), and use it to access the module exports.

In your case, if you have a `'../../components/tabs/tabs.component';` file with some lines like:

```
export class Tab {
...
export class Tabs {
```

You could, at another file, import them into a single variable through:

```
import * as TabsModule from '../../components/tabs/tabs.component';
```

An then access them using `TabsModule` as prefix. In other words:

- `Tab` becomes `TabsModule.Tab`; and
- `Tabs` becomes `TabsModule.Tabs`.

[Typescript handbook on Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) explains this well.

---

Ps.: Having multiple components in a file (`Tab` and `Tabs` both in `tabs.component.ts`) is considered a bad practice per [Angular2 Style Guide](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#04-10). The recommendation is to declare each component into its own file and create an `index` file which exports them at once -- see [Create Import Barrels](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#04-10).